# Ubuntu 14.04 says I have no space left

Tags: linux, ubuntu-14.04

I had been having issues trying to boot ubuntu. When the system had booted I had a blank locked screen. The mouse was able to move and I could access the terminal with `ctrl alt F2`but apart from this the computer was at a standstill.

Recently I fixed this issue with the command

```
sudo tune2fs -m1 /dev/sda5
```

This is not a recommended fix but it did allow me to access my desktop and use ubuntu apps. This command allows more space for the root user. Now that I am able to access my ubuntu apps I decided to install `BleachBit` which is the equivalent of `Windows auto cleaner`.

BleachBit has since crashed and now I get errors saying I have less that 4kb left of space.

Heres the question.  The laptop is dual booted. If I were to remove dual boot and use only one OS will this alleviate these issues?

Whats the best practice for maintaining ubuntu performance and speed?

Comment: You'd rather post this on SU.

Comment: Posting the output of `df -h` if you can get it to run would be helpful.

Comment: I'm going to echo the request for `df -h` output, particularly because if it's something like /var/ filling up with logfiles, not only would removing dualboot not fix anything; it'd also get rid of your dualboot functionality for no good reason, and can be more reasonably fixed with `logrotate` or similar tools (or, addressed by whatever application is likely misbehaving to generate such massive log files).

Answer (score 0):

> This command allows more space for the root user.

No, `tune2fs -m` sets the percentage of space reserved for the root user. 5% is a common default, so you just reduced the space available for the root user to 1% (`-m1`). What you did was increase the amount of space available to non-root users. So `sudo bleachbit` might allow it to run if that reserved space is available, since it will run with root privileges.

If you are dual booting off of one drive, then removing the partition(s) for the other OS and expanding the full Ubuntu partition into that space will give you more room for files.

Depending on your situation, cleaning out files taking up a lot of space and deleting unneeded apps will help to get you more space as well.

For best performance, keeping a drive at 75% full or less is a good rule. Depending on the size, it should still work fine up to 90% or 95%. But you need to be careful not to run into 100%, which is where you are at right now.

A few helpful commands for cleaning up packages are [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5980/how-do-i-free-up-disk-space) (applies to desktops as well).